# Testing: Unable to locate element

Tags: laravel, testing, browser, laravel-dusk

I learn testing. I created something like this:

```php
 $this->browse(function ($browser) {
        $browser->visit('/en/register')
                ->type('name', 'hello')
                ->type('email', 'asdsad@o2.pl')
                ->type('password', 'hello')
                ->type('password_confirmation', 'hello')
                ->click('register');
    });
```

I have the error:

> Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
>   Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body register"}
>   For test I want to testing standard register form.

Comment: `click()` expects a CSS selector. In your case probably `->click('.register')`.

Comment: I chanded it, but I have this error "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='name']"}". Type needs css selector too?

Comment: `type()` works with just the `name` attribute. Do you have an input or textarea with this name?

Comment: No. I have a standars register form: http://pasted.co/dfd4721a

Comment: `->type('name', 'hello')` should work. Please check the HTML with `$browser->dump()`: Does Dusk correctly load the `register` view?

Comment: I found the problem. This address works http://localhost:8000/en/register" and this not "/en/register". I have a new problem. No matter what i write in type. I can don't use some required field and dusk doesn't display any errors. For example this test is correctly for Dusk http://pasted.co/22280cfd

Comment: Can you take a screenshot? `$browser->screenshot('register');`

Comment: Now I have a message "This test did not perform any assertions". No matter that data is correct or not. I take a screenshot to incorrect data https://ibb.co/dv6cmd

Comment: Your latest paste (http://pasted.co/22280cfd) doesn't contain `->type('name', ...)`. Does your current code contain it?

Comment: Yes, I know.I but problem is when data is correct too. think that I know where is problem, but i don't know ow solve it. So when data is correct, Dusk take a screenshot page when user is redirectig after register. When data is wrong, It will dislay errors.

Comment: Shouldn't the user be redirected? What's the expected behaviour?